3d blender protruding type change key
I'm frustrated because the change isn't happening. How can I switch the Extrude function from the E key to a different type of extrusion?


Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service. 안녕하세요, 환영합니다. 이 사이트에서는 영어가 필수 언어입니다. 영어로 작성하기 어렵다면 온라인 번역 서비스를 자유롭게 이용해 주세요.

Use Alt-E to bring up the extrusion type menu or use the extrusion option on the Face menu on the top toolbar.
